# SonarQube complains about JpaRepository method name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, spring-repositories

How everybody solve code smells related to method name on interfaces that extends JpaRepository? In my case I have an `CpoWorkflowStepExecution` entity and I want to find by id and date.

CpoWorkflowStepExecution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cpo_workflow_step_execution", catalog = "cup_orchestrator")
public class CpoWorkflowStepExecution implements java.io.Serializable { 
    private Integer workflowStepExecutionId;
    private CpoWorkflowExecution cpoWorkflowExecution;
    private CpoWorkflowStep cpoWorkflowStep;
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
    private LocalDateTime finishDate;
    private String outcome;
    ...
```

WorkflowStepExecRep:

```
@Repository
public interface WorkflowStepExecRep extends JpaRepository<CpoWorkflowStepExecution, Integer>{

   Optional<CpoWorkflowStepExecution> findByCpoWorkflowStep_WorkflowStepIdAndFinishDateIsNull(String workflowStepId);
```

**SonarQube: Rename this method name to match the regular expression '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.**

Comment: Good day, could you include the CpoWorkflowStepExecution entity in your question please?

Comment: You can change the expression, if you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the method name by removing `_` character and it worked perfectly with SonarQube and JpaRepository:

```
findByCpoWorkflowStepWorkflowStepIdAndFinishDateIsNull
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data uses `_` to resolve ambiguity issues. You can find more details at [Working with Spring Data Repository - Property Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).

You might want to change Sonarqube's rule **java:S100**
from `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$` to `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)*$` but makes it possible to misuse